# Fragment not using full height of screen, but only after coming back from another Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have an `Activity` with a `TabLayout`, a `ViewPager2` and a `FragmentContainerView` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:context="com.safirecctv.easyview.activities.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/visiotech_red"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/visiotech_red"
            app:tabIconTint="?attr/tabLayoutTabColor"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorSecondary" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I first launch the `Activity` with its `Fragment` (I've reduced it to one tab and one fragment for the sake of simplicity), everything works as expected, the `Fragment` takes the whole screen. But when I come back from another `Activity` by calling:

```
mActivity?.finish()
```

The fragment loads well, but only takes half of the screen height. I've tried to inspect with Layout Inspector, but if I attach it before coming back, the app force closes, and if I attach it after (when the `Fragment` is loaded and only taking half of the screen height), then it recreates and works well again.

I am testing in a real device, not in the emulator.

This is my `Fragment` XML:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.safirecctv.easyview.viewmodels.main.DeviceManagementViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/list_view_devices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/listViewBackgroundColor"
            app:data="@{viewModel.devices}" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/visiotech_red"
            app:tint="?attr/buttonTextColor"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
package com.safirecctv.easyview.activities.add_edit_device.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.safirecctv.easyview.R
import com.safirecctv.easyview.databinding.ActivityAddEditDeviceIpddnsFragmentBinding
import com.safirecctv.easyview.viewmodels.add_edit_device.IpDdnsDeviceViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

/**
 * Fragment used to add or edit IP/DDNS devices to/from the database.
 * As of June, 2021, the following vendors support IP/DDNS login: Safire/Hikvision, XSecurity/Dahua, Uniview.
 */
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddEditIPDDNSDeviceFragment : Fragment(R.layout.activity_add_edit_device_ipddns_fragment) {
    private val mViewModel: IpDdnsDeviceViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityAddEditDeviceIpddnsFragmentBinding.bind(view)
        binding.apply {
            btnSaveDeviceIpDdns.setOnClickListener { trySaveDevice() }
            viewModel = mViewModel
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Device methods
    private fun trySaveDevice() {
        //mViewModel.trySaveDevice()
        activity?.finish()
    }
    //endregion
}
```

Could it be related to the fact that I'm not calling `onCreateView` in the Fragment but instead delegating it to the constructor?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I could open Layout Inspector finally, and this is what it shows: `RecyclerViewImpl` is taking the whole space but the `FrameLayout` inside it only takes like half of the screen: [image: Screenshot of Layout Inspector]

Comment: I tried setting 0dp height to the ViewPager, also tried to call myself `onCreateView`, removed the FragmentContainerView since I think it is useless, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. The problem was in the `Activity`'s XML. Everything was inside `AppBarLayout` and that was causing the issue. I just left the `MaterialToolbar` inside `AppBarLayout` and the rest as a sibling, as explained in [this post (in Spanish)](https://www.natapuntes.es/appbarlayout-toolbar-android/). Then everything started working as intended.